# Python парсинг проблема с вводом элементов

Tags: html, python, парсер

Возникла проблемка ,у меня должно выйти 134 элементов но почему то только 1 элемент

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url="https://www.zakon.kz/news/page/3/"
headers={'accept':'*/*'}
def z_parse(url,headers):
   session=requests.session()
   request=session.get(url,headers=headers)
   if request.status_code==200:
      soup=bs(request.content,'html.parser')
      divs=soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'column_728'})
      for div in divs:
         title=div.find('a',attrs={'target':'_blank'}).text
         print(title)
   else:
      print('ERROR')
print(z_parse(url,headers))
```

Comment: почему должно получиться 134 элементов - я увидел только один?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7NssI1D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Попробуйте следующий код:***

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/page/3/'


def parse(html: str) -> list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    links_to_the_news = soup.find('div', {'id': 'dle-content'}).find_all('a', {'target': '_blank'})

    headline_news = [link.get_text() for link in links_to_the_news]
    return headline_news


def main() -> None:
    html = requests.get(URL).text

    result = parse(html)
    print(*result, sep='\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```html
Ослабевшего лебедя спасли в Атырау
Почти вдвое может вырасти тариф на вывоз мусора
Трамп не исключил, что приедет в Москву на парад 9 мая
Забастовка "Люфтганзы" затронула Казахстан
В авиации не нужны доктора наук - ректор Академии гражданской авиации о проверке МОН
Влюбленная пара повесилась в лесу в СКО
В Казахстане запустят портал соцуслуг для людей с ограниченными возможностями
Гибель детей в Шымкенте. Специалисты исключили версию отравления пельменями
Фото с уткой на фоне Освенцима разгневало пользователей соцсетей
Макгрегор прошел ДНК-тест на отцовство ребенка вне брака
Аэропорт Алматы могут продать
Изменения в налогах и штрафах, нет браконьерству, регулирование АПК  – итоги недели
Назван легкий способ уберечься от самого частого рака
Мужчина, участвовавший в поисках пенсионерки, признался в ее убийстве в Туркестане
Павлодарским медучреждениям в этом году увеличили финансирование
Илон Маск рассказал, что нужно для создания колонии на Марсе
"Такая красивая, дай руку". Появилось видео спасения девушки в Караганде 
Девушка показала поразительное изменение после отказа от наркотиков
Тургумбаев рассказал о борьбе с терроризмом на Международной конференции в Будапеште
Девушка едва не спрыгнула с крыши многоэтажки в Караганде
Месячник здоровья. Более пяти тысяч алматинцев прошли осмотр врачей
Как развивается медицина в Акмолинской области
Месячник борьбы со СПИДом стартовал в Нур-Султане
В Алматы судью осудили за взятку
Сапарбаев рассказал павлодарцам, как реализуется послание Президента
Автобусники пожаловались на культуру пассажиров Алматы
История о мальчике, написавшем Токаеву, получила продолжение
Белку на Атакенте в Алматы демонтируют – акимат
Японец в Китае получил пожизненный срок за контрабанду наркотиков
Казахстанцы больше не смогут использовать фотошоп для прохождения техосмотра авто
В Академии правосудия состоялось посвящение в магистранты
Как украсят Алматы на Новый год
Токаев принял известного французского политического деятеля
Шпекбаев: Борьба с коррупцией может быть действительно эффективной
Стало известно о попытке изнасилования в поезде Петропавловск - Алматы
Казахстан погасил долг перед Китаем по проекту Астана LRT
Как цифровизация госуслуг в Алматы бьет по коррупции, рассказал Сагинтаев
Испытание воспитанием
Внесены изменения в Требования к созданию, функционированию и ликвидации фондов гарантирования исполнения обязательств по зерновым распискам, условия участия хлебоприемных предприятий в системе гарантирования исполнения обязательств по зерновым распискам (аннотация к документу от 23.10.2019)
Таксиста пытались убить в Талдыкоргане. Полиция после погони поймала преступников
Курсы валют на выходные дни
Взрывы в Бишкеке. Один человек погиб
Тимуржан Шакимов вновь назначен заместитель акима ЗКО
Курсы валют на выходные дни
Токаев и Путин вручили друг другу подарки
Дисквалификация директора компании (Калдыбаев А.К., кандидат юридических наук, магистр немецкого права (LL.M.); Асаинова Л.С., бакалавр права)
Тимуржан Шакимов вновь назначен заместитель акима ЗКО
Высокопоставленные дипломаты посетили карачаганакское месторождение
Фестиваль Земли пройдет в Казахстане в 2021 году
Смог в Алматы: высокого загрязнения воздуха не зафиксировано
Внесены изменения в постановление Правительства РК «О реализации Закона Республики Казахстан «О республиканском бюджете на 2019 - 2021 годы» (аннотация к документу от 28.10.2019)
Астанчанин заявил о падении лифта в многоэтажке
АО "БРК-Лизинг" награжден Евразийской премией в области авиационного лизинга 2019 года
Что нужно, чтобы аккредитоваться иностранным авиаперевозчикам в Казахстане
В столице ожидается метель
В Нур-Султане ВИЧ передается от матери к ребенку только в 1% случаев
Жестокое обращение с ребенком в детсаду украдкой сняли на видео
В чем секрет востребованного специалиста?
Внесены изменения в приказы Министра по инвестициям и развитию РК по вопросам иностранных воздушных перевозчиков (аннотация к документу от 25.10.2019)
В Бишкеке прогремели три взрыва в кафе
Аэропорт в Семее будет назван в честь Абая
Холдинг «Байтерек» продолжает развивать сотрудничество с российскими партнерами
Какие дороги в Казахстане станут платными в ближайшие два года
Утверждены Правила оказания платных видов деятельности по реализации услуг государственными учреждениями органов внутренних дел Республики Казахстан по оказанию медицинской помощи в рамках гарантированного объема бесплатной медицинской помощи и в системе обязательного социального медицинского страхования и расходования ими денег от реализации услуг (аннотация к документу от 28.10.2019)
Особый знак. Путин проводил Токаева в аэропорт в Омске
В Кокшетау пройдет фестиваль "Песня – душа народа"
Российского журналиста подозревают в вымогательстве денег у Кенеса Ракишева
"Пленили". Курьезный случай произошел около ЖК в Алматы
В суд не подавали. Акимат Алматинской области рассказал о спорных участках
"Астана" пропустила 5 голов и стала одной из худших в Лиге Европы
Кристина Агилера шокировала своими формами
Вакцинация – самая эффективная защита от гриппа
Холодные выходные ждут казахстанцев
Более 170 человек из ВКО подали документы для отбора в Президентский кадровый резерв
Дом, которого нет. Женщина собрала миллионы тенге с астанчан и скрылась
Участок дороги Нур-Султан - Щучинск снова открыли для всех видов транспорта
В Бескарагайском районе ВКО прошли дебаты кандидатов в партийный кадровый резерв
Путин прокатил Токаева по Омску на Aurus
Крупное ДТП с перевертышем произошло в Алматы
Мужчина воровал буквы с памятника воинам ВОВ в Нур-Султане
Лошадь, темнота: 70-летний мужчина погиб на трассе Алматы - Хоргос
Фонд "Даму" и российский "МСП Банк" договорились о сотрудничестве на форуме в Омске
Почему в Казахстане заметно подорожало мясо
Назначен новый генеральный консул Германии в Алматы
В Акмолинской области и Караганде сотрудники КУИС брали взятки
Медицина для каждого: на главном событии страны собрались представители здравоохранения
В Казахстане установят единые размеры выплат ветеранам к 75-летию Победы
Почему Академия гражданской авиации не прошла проверку МОН
«Соттағы татуластыру рәсімдері» жобасын іске асырудың қорытындылары
Почему в Казахстане заметно подорожало мясо
ПРАВМЕДИА: важные изменения 2019 года в госзакупках
Директор ТОО подозревается в присвоении 32 млн тенге, выделенных на рестраврацию театра
Прямые рейсы соединят Нур-Султан, Алматы и столицу Катара 
Назначен новый генеральный консул Германии в Алматы
Нигматулин провел заседание Бюро Мажилиса
В Британии установили личности 39 найденных в грузовике погибших
В элитном районе Алматы насмерть сбили лошадь
Алматинцы делятся фотографиями накрывшего город сильного смога
На трассе "Алматы-Екатеринбург" сгорел грузовой прицеп с шинами
Нигматулин провел заседание Бюро Мажилиса
Акимат Алматинской области требует от сельчан вернуть выданные участки
На летней резине. Тройное ДТП произошло в Алматы
Сколько дней отдохнут казахстанцы в декабре и на Новый год
15 ноября истекает срок представления налоговой отчетности за 3-й квартал 2019 года
Жизнь казахстанцев в 10 раз дешевле жизни граждан России что ли?! – Перуашев
Что ждет технологию блокчейн в 2020 году
Бакауов: Транспортный коридор между Казахстаном и Россией по Иртышу нужно восстановить
Токаев и Путин обсудили открытие российско-казахстанских школ
Холдинг "Байтерек" продолжает развивать сотрудничество с российскими партнерами
Какие дороги в Казахстане станут платными в ближайшие два года
Дарига Назарбаева призвала навести порядок в сфере оказания госуслуг
Токаев подвел итоги XVI Форума межрегионального сотрудничества в Омске
На трассе Нур-Султан - Щучинск ограничено движение для некоторого транспорта
Токаев не оставил без внимания письмо школьника 
В аэропорту Уральска провалился фундамент
В Алматы задержан мужчина, продававший автозапчасти, которых не имел
Дождь, снег, гололед - погода в пятницу
О таможенной процедуре таможенного транзита
Шубы, золото и сейф с деньгами похитили в Туркестанской области
Плохого ничего он не сделал - соседи о наркобароне из СКО
Американский миллиардер составит конкуренцию Трампу на выборах
800 человек пострадали от укусов бродячих собак в Усть-Каменогорске
Из функций таможенных органов исключены обязанности проведения ветеринарно-санитарного и карантинного фитосанитарного контроля
Миллениалов ждет бедность и быстрая смерть - исследование
Молодежная сборная Казахстана по хоккею проиграла второй сборной Латвии
Ни на что не жаловался - директор об умершем на тренировке школьнике
Об изменениях и дополнениях, внесенных в Налоговый кодекс
Австралиец разбогател через минуту после расставания с девушкой
Десятки ДТП произошли из-за гололеда в Караганде
Умер модельер Патрик-Луи Виттон
Мировой долг достиг рекорда Второй мировой войны
Почти 10 млрд тенге налогов уплатили граждане Казахстана в рамках налоговой амнистии
В Таразе найден пропавший 10-летний мальчик
Бабушка неделю прожила в квартире с трупом в Уральске
В результате ДТП водителя Hyundai Galloper сбил его же автомобиль
```